# Get currentuser after reload the page

Tags: google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I have added google login to my website, it is working and after the success authentication I can retrive user profile but when I reload the page (press F5) I lose the authenticated user profile. How can I retrieve the authenticated user profile? I have added a cookie to maintain the session but I cant get the user profile by google-signin library.

These are my use cases:

- A) Without reload the page -> Working

  1. Open the website
  2. Sign in with google account
  3. Browse in the website
  4. Logout from the website.
- B) Reloading the page -> **Issue**

  1. Open the website
  2. Sign in with google account
  3. Browse in the website
  4. Reload the website.
  5. Logout from the website. (Issue because I lost the authenticated user after the reload and it shows an issue in the next code)

  ```
  const auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
  await auth2.signOut())
  ```

Thanks in advance.